# How to make the tableHeaderView bounce along with UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a tableHeaderView that is a large UIImageView. I want the UIImageView to stretch out when someone overscrolls to compensate for the space that would otherwise be empty.

I had that working before when using a simple UIScrollView, but it seems that I can't get it to work in a UITableViewCell, because setting the 'y' parameter of the UIImageView to a negative value seems to result in it being set to 0, as it doesn't want to overflow. The height does change though, so the delegate is setup correctly.

This is the code that is related to updating the frame in realtime:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pos = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (pos <= 0){
        let height = self.view.frame.width - pos;
        self.picture!.frame = CGRectMake(0, pos, self.size().width, height);
    }
}
```

Should I change any settings on the UITableView to achieve the wanted effect?

**EDIT**
An example of what I wish to achieve: 
[image]

Comment: Try using offset and height constraints in the UIImageView rather than frame setting. Change the constraints and reload the cell.

Comment: Could you give me a quick example?

Comment: What you're trying won't work because the tableview will reposition the header on scroll. A hack you could try: instead of setting your image as the tableheaderview, put a view in there that's the same size as your image when not stretched so there is space in the tableview for your image. Then add your imageview as a subview of the tableview and use your scroll delegate logic to move it around. You'll have to take care of when the imageview should scroll off the screen as well.

Comment: @jasongregori You can actually get this to work as required as long as you don't clip the header cell subviews. By moving the image outside and above of the header cell with no clipping and increasing its height you can fill the gap created when you pull down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given this a try and it is possible using the following approach:

1) Use a header view for the top cell. You provide this via the delegate `viewForHeaderInSection`.

2) Create this header view using a prototype cell to make life easy for yourself. Remember to return cell.contentView as the view.

3) Create a property for the header cell in your view controller.

```
self.headerCell;
```

4) In `viewForHeaderInSection` when you get section 0, if the `self.headerCell` property is nil, create the cell and configure. Otherwise return the existing `self.headerCell.contentView`

5) Define the prototype cell as follows:

a) Create a cell with a UIImageView and give the image view the following constraints:

i) Pin left and trailing edges to the contentView of the cell.

ii) Pin the top to the contentView top

iii) Give it a height constraint which is set to the height of the cell.

b) CTRL drag the top constraint and height constraint into the class for the header view cell and create IBOutlets. Lets call them `constraintTop` and `constraintHeight`.

6) VERY IMPORTANT. For the header cell `contentView` deselect clip subviews in the attribute inspector. Otherwise you can not see outside of the bounds of the cell.

7) In your table view controller add:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"Scrolling pos = %f,%f",scrollView.contentOffset.x,scrollView.contentOffset.y);

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0){
        self.headerCell.constraintHeight.constant=self.headerCell.frame.size.height-scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        self.headerCell.constraintTop.constant=scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        [self.headerCell layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

The result of this is that when you drag down, the constraints for the image height are increased and its position is moved up. Layout forces it to redisplay which causes it to fill in the gap. You can play around with this function to get the exact effect you want. Much depends on the display mode you set for the image.

I have tried this using a UIView with a background color and it works well.

You will need some tidy up when scrolling stops to set the constraints back to 0 and the height of the cell.